# Comparing the torus and a small wedge product, and their universal coverings

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following problem:

> Let $A = S^1 \times S^1$ and $B = S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$. Compute their universal coverings. Prove that $A$ and $B$ have isomorphic homology groups for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, but that their universal coverings do not.

I haven't had much practice, so I was wondering if my reasoning is sound. Also, there are some questions mixed in (bolded). Anyway, my work:

> $A$ has universal cover since the product of covers is a cover (so
>   given the universal cover of $S^1$, I get a cover of $S^1 \times
>  S^1$). But $\mathbb{R^2}$ is contractible, so I know this is the
>   universal cover of $A$. For $B$, I have an idea of what the covering
>   space is (I think its exactly the same as the universal cover for $S^1
>  \vee S^1$, except a copy of $S^2$ is attached to each node in the
>   graph). **I'm not entirely sure if this is correct**, but we tried
>   some simple examples of this in class (computing universal covers of
>   small wedge products), and this is what I thought to do; **is there a
>   reference, other than Hatcher, that explains why I can construct the
>   universal cover in this manner**?
>
> The homology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=0$ and is
>   trivial for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ; in particular $H_2(\mathbb{R^2})=0$.
>   On the other, let $U_B$ be the universal cover of $B$. Since the
>   universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^1$ is contractible, it follows that
>   $U_B$ deformation retracts onto (and is homotopy equivalent to) the
>   wedge of countably many copies of $S^2$. Thus, by additivity of
>   homology over wedge sums, $H_n(U_B) = \oplus_{\mathbb{N}} H_n(S^2)$;
>   in particular, $H_2(U_B)=\oplus_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$, so in
>   dimension 2, $A$ and $B$ have non-isomorphic homology groups.
>
> Again, using additivity of homology of wedge sums, the homology groups
>   of $B$ are given by $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$
>   for $n=0$; $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ for $n=1$; $\mathbb{Z}$ for
>   $n=2$; and is trivial for $n \geq 3$. **My main problem is that I'm
>   not sure how to compute the homology groups for a torus. Working only
>   from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, is there a way to compute the
>   homology groups for a torus?**

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Be careful with your use of the term "deformation retracts onto". A deformation retract is from a space to one of its subspaces.

Comment: Note that **reduced** homology is additive for wedge sums, so you might like to rethink the $0$th homology of $B$.

Comment: You can compute the homology of the torus $S^1\times S^1$ directly from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (assuming you know $H_*(S^1)$) by using Mayer Vietoris where $U$ and $V$ are cylinders overlapping on their boundaries.

Comment: Oh shoot! Thanks, Daniel! I'll take a look at these hints and come back if I have any other questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your universal cover for $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ is correct. Check this by showing what the covering map is!